# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity windows suddenly resemble Windows 95

Tags: unity, 16.04, gui, window

Recent installation of Ubuntu 16.04, unity.

For some reason the windows for some applications have started looking "strange"; I'm not sure how best to describe it, they look like the old Microsoft Windows 3.1 style windows and controls.  I have attached a screenshot of an example (The music program audacious).

How do I fix this?  I found nothing while searching, and I don't know enough about this kind of stuff to know what to do.  Thanks.

[image]

Logging out and logging back in do not help with this.  Changing the theme does not help.  The only desktop I have going on is Unity.  WINE is installed, but that was installed several days ago, this began happening long after the installation of WINE.

Comment: Does the problem persist after logging out and logging back in?

Comment: Ubuntu by default comes with 3 themes. Have you tried switching through some of them ? If you try that, does the issue persist ?

Comment: logging out and logging back in does not fix this.  Changing the themes does not fix this.

Comment: Have you recently installed Wine?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? Is it Unity or something like Gnome Fallback? Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: David Foerster:  I am using only Unity.  (PS:  I'm not sure if you meant that I should respond to peoples' questions in the comments AND to edit my original question, or to respond to peoples' questions by editing the original question and not responding via comments at all.)